# HP MSA 2040 for SVOD service

Tags: hp, realtime

Is HP-MSA-2040 suitable for SVOD service with around 100 Terabyte of real time data short term and 1 petabyte long term?
what kind of disk is recommended for the SAN?(considering throughput and size) SSD or SAS HDD (the file sizes are around 3 and 3.5 gigabyte)
system has around 900.000 subscribers in long term but for now is has 20.000 subscribers.

security and upgrade ability along with FC is important.

Answer (score 5):

I would not recommend that product for the scale and capacity you're seeing.

Performance would be fine, but the HP MSA2040 is a low-end SAN. It's better to step up to a more purpose-built solution that starts closer to your desired capacity.

Comment: what kind of SAN do you suggest?

Comment: I can't give any recommendation really... other than the MSA 2040 is a bit low-rent for the capacity you speak of.

Comment: i was thinking about number of MSA-2040 synced with each other for the capacity and i don't think it's impossible. then why do you saying it doesn't fit?

Comment: any more answers?

Comment: @hsp my job for the last decade has been building VOD platforms - generally speaking you can't just buy a single product and expect it to do everything you need - you need experience of your user base and a better understanding of the impact they have on your IO requirements. Our team is around 100 but we support about 4m users so don't assume you can do all of this on your own. We use a combination of HPE 3Par and NetApp FAS8000 series boxes to actually hold our content then use Brocade Steelapp/VTM to cache what we can. Basically it's not easy and the 2040 is good but low-end.

Comment: thanks for reply and i don't want to do all this on my own my job is to find a solution for storage needs of my company and i don't have many intel on other things and units but if you could help me with this i would appreciate

Comment: @hsp what is your budget?

Comment: there is no budget limitation for this solution the only thing is to provide the base that has the ability to upgrade in future for example providing around 50 TB for now and would be upgraded  to PB for long term as i said before.

Comment: Well, you could definitely pay for some consulting advice to help select a solution :) I'm available!

Comment: it's ok what should i do?

Comment: From my experience, asking for assistance from those big guys representatives helps lots. Dell, HP, IBM and others are willing to help you design solutions to fit your needs. Best part is you no need to pay for @ewwhite's help ;)

Comment: yes i'm aware of that and i appreciate for the time they and others giving to answer my questions.

Comment: Except I have resources and know how to work the system :) But I'd probably be looking at Nimnle storage, EMC, Netapp... Depending on budget, performance profile and expansion needs.

Comment: we need 625 KB read for each user and we don't need much write . the number of the users is the problem.i mean the concurrency  . for now it's going to be around 20.000 users. but based on our calculation we assuming around 100.000 by the end of the year. and one more question is that how much cache we gonna need assuming 50/50 active , deactive users?

Comment: @chopper3 is the best resource here.

Comment: i have about a month to find a solution for this part of our network core other parts are going to be completed after this and are related to this unit so any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: @hsp are you only on the hook for the storage side of this or for the web front end and security/network too? where are you in the world? perhaps we could do a quick skype call or similar?

Comment: i think it's better to have a skype call if that's okay with you so i could describe the whole project.i live in iran - mashhad and the project firs phase is going to be done in this city however it's a long story. so could you give me your skype id? (and one more thing is that i would pay for your solutions just if you could give me some of your time) thanks

Comment: I'm in the UK, it's a bit late here - I'll come back tomorrow or Monday to arrange ok.

Comment: OK sorry to keep you up so late. we have about 3.5 hour difference in time . i'll be ready when ever you call

Comment: @Chopper3 i'm waiting for your call . could you tell me specific time so i could be online on that time.thanks

Comment: Sorry, busy day, may have to wait until Friday now sorry - got a business trip tues-thurs

Comment: OK i'll wait until friday but could you tell me the clock?

Comment: @Chopper3 would you please give me a skype id or gmail so I could talk to you , today is Friday by the way , I would be thankful if you could answer sooner , thanks!